# Solution interval for $\dot x(t)=x(t)^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

In my course notes, the professors introduces the example ODE:

$$
\dot x(t)=x(t)^2
$$

The solution is:

$$
x(t)=\frac{c}{1-tc}
$$

However, this is undefined (division by zero) for $t=1/c$. The professors says **no solution is defined for $t\ge 1/c$**. While I agree that no solution exists for $t=1/c$, help me understand why we cannot also have the solution for $t>1/c$, where $x(t)$ by the above formula is perfectly well defined (no division by zero)?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The solution of an IVP is a continuously differentiable function. Thus the solution ends at the pole, even if the function has values after the pole.

Or to put it differently, the domain of the solution is always one interval.

Comment: This is a control theory course, the professor defined the solution of an IVP to be only *piecewise continuous* (weaker than what you say). The problem still persists because the solution in this case is not piecewise continuous?

Comment: Yes. And I think it should be continuous and piecewise continuously differentiable. The derivative defines a velocity field, the trajectory follows that velocity field. There is no velocity that can transport you from plus to minus infinity.